# Ember: Return a value or set a model property from Ember promise

Tags: ember.js

**Update - more information below**

If I have a promise, is it possible to return a value from it?

```
let itemData = [];
model.data.get('products').then(relatedItems => {
  relatedItems.forEach(function(item,index) {
    console.log(item.get('name')); // Product 1, Product 2 etc
    itemData.pushObject(item);
  });
},reject => {
  console.log('error '+reject);
});
```

If I try and return the itemData array after the promise has resolved I get undefined.

Alternatively (and preferably) I'd like to be able to set a model property when the promise has resolved:

```
// component code 

itemData:null,
init() {
  let model = this.get('data');
  model.data.get('products').then(relatedItems => {
     relatedItems.forEach(function(item,index) {
        this.set('itemData',item);
     });
  },reject => {
     console.log('error');
  });
}
```

The reason for all of this is that I need to sort the product items which I can only access via the promise (in this example). Having set the itemData property I was intending to do something like:

```
sortedItems:computed.sort('itemData','sortProperties'),
sortProperties:['name:desc']
```

**More information:**

In my product route, product.items.item I have a pagination component

```
 {{pagination-item-trad data=model}}
```

The model hook in the route product.items.item is

```
  model(params) {
    let itemModel = this.store.findRecord('product',params.id);
    let mainModel = this.modelFor('product.items');

    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
       data:itemModel,
       mainData:mainModel
    });
}
```

The mainModel will include the category model for that particular product item.

Since the product-category model has a many-to-many relationship with products, I need to access the product data in my component using a promise, which was not a problem until I needed to sort the product data. What I am trying to do is obtain the product information from the promise (itemData below) and then use that in the computed property. So the question is how I can extract the data from the promise for use elsewhere in the code? Is there a better way to achieve this? I hope this is clearer!

```
 sortedItems:computed.sort('itemData','sortProperties'),
 sortProperties:['name:desc']
```

The component in more detail:

```
 import Ember from 'ember';
 const {computed} = Ember;

 export default Ember.Component.extend({
   itemData:null,  // i would like to set this within the promise
   sortedItems:computed.sort('itemData','sortProperties'),
   sortProperties:['name:desc'],
   init() {
    let allData = this.get('data');
    let mainModel = allData.mainData;
    var self = this; 
    let itemData = [];
    mainModel.data.get('products').then(relatedItems => {
        relatedItems.forEach(function(item,index) {
        console.log(item.get('name')); // prints Product 1 etc etc
        itemData.pushObject(item);
    });
    self.set('itemData',itemData); // I can't do this
    },reject => {
      console.log('error '+reject);
    });
  }
  // rest of code omitted for brevity
});
```

Comment: There is a typo on the line 5, missing "'":
`let model = this.get('data^);`

Comment: Can you set a computed property dependent on the model?
`sorted: Ember.computed('data.model.products',function(){
 return this.get('data.model.products').filter(...);
});`

Comment: It wont work since he's using promises.

Comment: This question is poorly constructed hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. But it looks like a case for Ember.PromiseArray. If you could give your model + controller + template code. We would easily solve this for you.

Comment: Many thanks for getting back - apologies for the typo in line 5 - corrected.Will amend the question shortly to give more detail - sorry I thought it was clear, apologies if not.

Comment: Hi Kristjan, I have provided more information in the original question - I hope that helps. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scope is wrong inside your `forEach`, `this` no longer points to your component.  You can either use another fat arrow or maintain a reference to the component scope using a variable.

Additionally, I doubt you are meaning to iterate and overwrite `itemData` on each iteration.

Comment: Hi Kingpin, many thanks for getting back. Sorry - yes, I meant to try and set itemData outside of the forEach loop! I have made some adjustments but still struggling to achieve the desired result here. If I try and get itemData elsewhere in the code (for use in the computed property) I still get undefined?

Comment: Where else are you using it, I just see the sort, are you sure the promise has been resolved when you are trying to get that property?

Comment: Yes, the promise has resolved. If I try and set itemData in the way I've shown, can I use that value elsewhere in the component js file? I've done something similar before when setting a component property but I've only used that in the template file..... Am I able to do this? Does it seem reasonable to try and set this itemData property and then use that in the computed property to achieve the sorting? I would then want to use the sortedItems in a forEach loop elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Yes, most definitely, since it's asynchronous you'll need to take into account the potential null array reference though.

Comment: Hi, I've got it working ... making the call to the function which uses the data from the promise within the promise block rather than outside of it, which of course is why I was always getting a null value! Many thanks for your help - much appreciated.